# C++ Error C2061: syntax error : identifier

Tags: c++

When I try to compile this code I get these Errors:

```
Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'stammdaten' 
Error   2   error C2660: 'Test_Lohnab::Gehaltsrechner' : function does not take 1 arguments 
Error   3   error C2511: 'int Test_Lohnab::Gehaltsrechner(stammdaten &)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Test_Lohnab'
```

It would be a big help, if someone could explain me what i did wrong.

This is my code:

```
//Test_Lohnab.h

#pragma once

#include <iostream>

#include <string>



class Test_Lohnab 

{

public:

    Test_Lohnab();

    ~Test_Lohnab();

    int Gehaltsrechner(stammdaten &st);//, abrechnung &ab);
}


class stammdaten
{
public:
    std::string name;
    std::string strasse;
    std::string ort;
    ….

    public:
        stammdaten();
        ~stammdaten();

        stammdaten(std::string n, std::string s, std::string o, int st, int fa, int k, int a,     double z, double kver, double pk, int mi, int pv, int os, int ps, int ki, double geb,
            double jf, double jh, int G_c, int G_a_c, int r_c, int A_L_c, double U_1, double U_2,     double bb_g);
}
```

```
//Test_Lohnab.cpp

#include "Test_Lohnab.h"

#include <iostream>



Test_Lohnab::Test_Lohnab()
{
}



Test_Lohnab::~Test_Lohnab()
{
}



stammdaten::stammdaten()
{
}

stammdaten::stammdaten(std::string n, std::string s, std::string o, int st, int fa, int k, int a, double z, double kver, double pk, int mi, int pv, int os, int ps, int ki, double geb,
double jf, double jh, int G_c, int G_a_c, int r_c, int A_L_c, double U_1, double U_2, double bb_g)
: name(n), strasse(s), ort(o), stkl(st), f(fa), krv(k), abv(a), zkf(z), kv(kver), pkpv(pk), mitag(mi), pvz(pv), ost(os), pvs(ps), kist(ki), gebjahr(geb), jfreib(jf), jhinzu(jh),
Gleitzone_check(G_c), Gleitzone_alt_check(G_a_c), rente_check(r_c), AN_Lst_check(A_L_c), U1(U_1), U2(U_2), bbg(bb_g)
{
}

int main()
{
    system("PAUSE");

    stammdaten Personstamm1{ "Klaus Müller", "Parkstrasse 12", "78578 Monopoly", 1, 1000, 1, 1, 0, 15.5, 0.0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 9, 1982, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.7, 0.38, 0 };

    /**/
    Test_Lohnab Ablauf;
    Ablauf.Gehaltsrechner(Personstamm1);           //, Abrechnung1);
    system("PAUSE");
    /**/
}

int Test_Lohnab::Gehaltsrechner(stammdaten &Test1)//, abrechnung &Abrech1)
{
}
```

Comment: both classes are missing semicolons after the closing `}`. Also: In which line do these errors occur?

Comment: Error 1 in int Gehaltsrechner(stammdaten &st, abrechnung &ab); this was my fault actually there are semicolons i just tried to decrease the code so it is better to see.

Comment: Why do you copy the strings twice in stammdaten constructor?

Comment: i do? i thought this is how the element-initializer works.

Comment: Error 2 is when i want to call the function in the main function. And Error 3 is in: int Test_Lohnab::Gehaltsrechner(stammdaten &Test1, abrechnung &Abrech1){} when the function is called

Comment: @Mikehen yes, you do. In every function `void f(type a){}` a is copied. You can avoid this by passing a reference `void f(type& a){}`. But now you say: "but `f` can alter `a`" to avoid that, there is `void f(const type& a){}`. Welcome to SO, by the way!

Comment: Ohh i see. Yes it seems better this way. :) Thanks. Hello Community and hello niklasfi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your classes `Test_Lohnab` function `int Gehaltsrechner` needs an object of the type `stammdaten` which the compiler does not yet know about because it is defined afterwards. You can use forward declaration to inform him about it. Simply add the following line after your `includes`

```
class stammdaten;
```

Comment: or, since `stammdaten` does not seem to depend upon `Test_Lohnab`, he could define `stammdaten` first, and `Test_Lohnab` afterwards.

Comment: Ohh yes that solves the problem. Thank you good sir. Life could be so easily.

Comment: Just a thank you for this answer. It solved the same problem for me.